# Injecting dependancies in imported modules in nestjs tests

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am working with a Nestjs app that has a module, let's call it ThisModule which has a controller called ControllerForThisModule and a service called ServiceForThisModule where I am injecting a MongoDB model called ModelForThisModule. ThisModule also imports another module called OtherModule where I am injecting a model called ModelInOtherModule. Now, when I run the test, I get the error below?

```
 Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ModelInOtherModule (?). Please make sure that the argument DatabaseConnection at index [0] is available in the MongooseModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If DatabaseConnection is a provider, is it part of the current MongooseModule?
- If DatabaseConnection is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MongooseModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing DatabaseConnection */ ]
```

This is my code that runs before every test, I am mocking ModelForThisModule using the getModelToken('ModelForThisModule'). However, how do I inject a mock model for ModelInOtherModule for the module OtherModuleWithAModel?

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [
        ServiceForThisModule, {
        provide: getModelToken('ModelForThisModule'),
        useClass: ModelMock
        }
    ],
    imports: [
        OtherModuleWithAModel
    ],
    controllers: [ControllerForThisModule],
    }).compile();
    
    controller = module.get(B2cDataMealplanFixedSetController);
    service = module.get(B2cDataMealplanFixedSetService);
});
```

Makes sense? or leave a comment if the question is not clear enough

Comment: what if you use the `overrideProvider` method like [it is used here](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing)?

Comment: When unit testing, there should only be one actual instance of a class. Everything else should be mocks. In this case, what are you testing, the controller? You should be able to get rid of the `imports` and just use `providers` to add whatever mocks you need